# How can I add legend to multiple hlines in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend, geom-hline

Can anyone help me out with some task?
I have to add 3 `geom_hline()` to a plot. 
One of them is a line that shows the recommended spacing for threes in a forest, and the others are the acceptable upper and lower limits of variation in spacing. 
To do so, I'm using `geom_hline()`, but I'm having a hard time to show the legends in a right way.
Also, the two limits have the same linetype (dashed), being red, and the other one is a solid line in blue color.
Therefore, how can I add legends to these three hlines?
 
Remembering that I need to have two elements in the legend: brief description of the red dashed line as limit and brief description of the blue solid lines as recommended spacing.
Thanks a lot, guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To show a legend in a `ggplot`, you should create an aesthetic mapping. The simplest way to do that is to have a seperate little data frame that contains the information you want to show on your `hline`s.

You haven't provided any sample data, so I've made some up here so that this is a fully reproducible example:

```r
library(ggplot2)

set.seed(69)
main_data <- data.frame(x = rnorm(200, 10), y = rnorm(200, 10))
hline_data <- data.frame(y = c(8, 10, 12), type = factor(c(2, 1, 2)), 
                         stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

ggplot(main_data, aes(x,y)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  geom_hline(data = hline_data, 
             aes(yintercept = y, linetype = type, colour = type)) +
  scale_colour_manual(values = c("blue", "red"), 
                      labels = c("Recommended Spacing", "Limits of spacing"),
                      name = "Key") +
  scale_linetype_manual(values = 1:2, 
                        labels = c("Recommended Spacing", "Limits of spacing"),
                        name = "Key")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-05-19 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: thanks once more! It's not the first time you helped me a lot here. Your solution worked very well for me and helped me to understand certain things about the legends.

Comment: I was not aware of this. I'm new at stackoverflow. Thanks for the tip. I'll do that to the other questions I've made.